# Spring Batch - ItemWriter is writing same object read by ItemReader but not the one returned after processing through ItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

My scenario is: `JdbcPagingItemReader` is reading from Oracle db and returning Object let say 'Employee'. Then this '`Employee`' object is passed to Processor to make another call to db to pull more information from multiple tables and return '`AggregatedEmployee`' object (it actually extends Employee). I am using `KafkaItemWriter` to write the processed object to Kafka but rather than writing `AggregatedEmployee`, writer is trying to write 'Employee' itself.

@Mahmoud Ben Hassine: I have seen your lot of suggestions on Spring Batch.Please share your thoughts.

ProcessorInterface Code:

```
public interface PageProcessor<T> {
       <R extends Employee> R process(T page);
}
```

Step Bean Code:

```
@Bean
protected Step step1 (CompositeJdbcPagingItemReader <Employee> reader, KafkaItemWriter <String, AggregatedEmployee> writer) {
    return steps.get("step1")
                .<Employee, AggregatedEmployee>chunk(5).
                reader(reader).
                writer(writer).build();
    }
```

Implementation Class of ProcessorInterface Code:

```
public class EmployeeProcessor implements PageProcessor<Employee> {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <R extends Employee> R process(Employee page) {
             ... implementation goes here
    }
```

KafkaItemWriter Bean:

```
    @Bean
    KafkaItemWriter<String,AggregatedEmployee> writer(){
        return new KafkaItemWriterBuilder<String, AggregatedEmployee>()
                .kafkaTemplate(aggregatedEmployeekafkaTemplate)
                .itemKeyMapper(aggregatedEmployee -> String.valueOf(aggregatedEmployee.getEmployeeId()))
                .build();
    }
```

Edited to show processor:

```
public class CompositeJdbcPagingItemReader<T> extends JdbcPagingItemReader<T> {
    private PageProcessor<T> pageProcessor;

    public void setPageProcessor(PageProcessor<T> pageProcessor) {
        this.pageProcessor = pageProcessor;
    }
```

And when Reader bean is created, processor object is also created and set into reader through above shown setter and processor logic written in EmployeeProcessor is also getting executed.

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sample.model.Employee cannot be cast to class com.sample.model.AggregatedEmployee (com.sample.model.Employee and com.sample.model.AggregatedEmployee are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.batch.item.KeyValueItemWriter.write(KeyValueItemWriter.java:43)
```

Comment: Remove that `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and check where the warning is. Your types are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set the processor on your step:

```
@Bean
protected Step step1 (CompositeJdbcPagingItemReader <Employee> reader, KafkaItemWriter <String, AggregatedEmployee> writer) {
return steps.get("step1")
            .<Employee, AggregatedEmployee>chunk(5).
            reader(reader).
            writer(writer).build();
}
```

You need to set the processor which will do the type conversion `Employee` -> `AggregatedEmployee` on your step.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my processor was configured in reader itself like shown below. See edited piece of code above

Comment: That's not a good idea, your reader is doing two things at the same time and is coupled to your processor. Moreover, Spring Batch will not call your processor so the conversion `Employee` to `AggregatedEmployee` won't happen which is the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Ben Hassine. I separated processor out from reader and everything worked as expected.